# Persona 3 lighting glitch on PS3?

Tags: ps3, persona-3-fes

I'm playing Persona 3 FES on the PS3, downloaded from the PSN, and I've noticed certain light-colored textures in the game are flashing and very bright -- for example, the tubas in the music room, or (more painfully) the walls of the top block of Tartarus. Is this the result of anything I can control? Some setting on the PS3 or on my TV perhaps? It's starting to give me a headache.

An example of what I mean (note that the capture software in this video dulls the effect some, it's much brighter on my tv):

Comment: If this wasn't the same in the original PS2 version, then this is probably an emulation error. Have you tried disabling some emulation settings? Specifically, [upscaling/smoothing](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps3/current/settings/gamesettings.html#2434)

Comment: @JohnoBoy That's the sort of thing I was wondering about; unfortunately, a quick test reveals that with both those settings turned off, the game looks worse but the flashing remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For lack of a better answer, this does in fact appear to be an error in emulation that is not fixable. :(